# String regex matching in Erlang

Tags: regex, string, erlang

How would I do regex matching in Erlang?

All I know is this:
f("AAPL" ++ Inputstring) -> true.

The lines that I need to match
"AAPL,07-May-2010 15:58,21.34,21.36,21.34,21.35,525064\n"

In Perl regex:    ^AAPL,* (or something similar)

In Erlang?

Comment: In this case the example you give WILL match the string so I assume that you are really after a more general case. In that case use the 're' module as has been answered.

Comment: If you're just matching the first five exact characters of a string, regex is about the slowest and most complicated way you can do it.

Comment: @Dustin the first five characters are dynamic. So what do you suggest?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say the characters are dynamic.  For the example you've given, there's no language in which I'd use a regex.  The match is too simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`re`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) module, e.g.:

```
...
String = "AAPL,07-May-2010 15:58,21.34,21.36,21.34,21.35,525064\n",
RegExp = "^AAPL,*",
case re:run(String, RegExp) of
  {match, Captured} -> ... ;
  nomatch -> ...
end,
...
```

Comment: Equivalent to `re:run(String, RegExp)`

Comment: How is this different to running =>  regexp:first_match(Line, "^AAPL,*" ) ?

Comment: Well, it may not be different, but according to the regexp module documentation 'it has been obsoleted by the re module and will be removed in a future release'. So, you should definitely prefer the re module.

Comment: just to precise, the match in the case clause is actually {match,ListOfMatchArea} where ListOfMatchArea is in the form [{A,B}]