# Translate PCRE to RabbitMQ/Erlang regex

Tags: regex, rabbitmq, erlang

I'm setting up user accounts and permissions for RabbitMQ.
The idea is that users are called "user1, "user2",... and there is a separate queue "all-users" that - you guessed it - all users can access.

I came up with the following regex:

```
^user[0-9]+|all\-users$
```

and tested it at https://regex101.com/

```
bob [no match]
alice [no match]
user5 [match]
user99 [match]
user [no match]
all-users [match]
```

It works as expected.
However, the same is not true for my RabbitMQ.
Specifically, when publishing to `all-users` using any `user{n}` account, I get a `403 - ACCESS REFUSED`.
If I change the write permission to `.*` it works fine, but that's not what I want.

I also tried the following modifications to my regex, none of which work in RabbitMQ but they mostly do in regex101:

- `^user[0-9]+|^all-users$` (without escaping the dash)
- `^(user[0-9]+|all-users)$` (with just one set of brackets)
- `^user[0-9]+|^all\\-users$` (double-escaping the dash - doesn't work)
- `^(user[0-9]+)|(all\-users)$` (using groups)
- `(^user[0-9]+$)|(^all\-users$)` (using the start/end markers in the groups)
- `^user[0-9]+|^all\-users` (leaving out the end marker - also in combination with the groups)
- `user[0-9]+|all-users` (leaving out all markers)

I know other people have asked similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880588/pcre-regex-to-erlang-regex) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828160/string-regex-matching-in-erlang)) but (like my own question) they're all rather specific and don't help me much with my problem.

P.S.:
I'm using the RabbitMQ Management UI to set the permissions for easier debugging but setting them on the command line has exactly the same effect [image: RabbitMQ Managenment UI]

Comment: First of all, the regex must be `^(user[0-9]+|all-users)$`, with a group to make anchors affect all the alternatives.

Comment: That doesn't work either - with or without escaping the dash :(

Comment: Yeah, most probably, because the method you are using does not accept regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so after a good night's sleep I had another look at the (not brilliant) RabbitMQ documentation.

I'd based my example on the documentation for [`rabbitmqctl`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#set_permissions), where it shows how to set permissions "on all resources whose names starts with "janeway-"":

```
"^janeway-.*"
```

However, the [access control docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authorisation) contain a table of permissions required for different operations. The `basic.publish` operation (publishing a message to a queue) requires (quite counter-intuitively for me) write permissions on the *exchange*, not the queue.
I had not been using a custom exchange, leaving the field empty in my python code which - apparently - resulted in the default exchange (`amq.default`) being used. The problem was that the user account I had been using had permissions to access resources that were named "user1", "user2",... and "all-users", but that does not include `amq.default`.

**TL;DR**:

The permissions should have been

```
^(user[0-9]+|all-users|amq.default)$
```

or a variant thereof.